# Altering multiple text files using grep awk sed perl or something else

Tags: matlab, sed, awk, grep, octave

I have multiple text files named split01.txt, split02.txt etc... with the data in the format below: **(This is what I have)**

```
/tmp/audio_files/n000001.wav;
/tmp/audio_files/n000002.wav;
/tmp/audio_files/n000003.wav;
/tmp/audio_files/p000004.wav;
/tmp/audio_files/p000005.wav;
```

I would like to create another file with the data taken from the split01.txt, split02.txt etc... file in the format below: **(this is the format I would like to see)**

```
[playlist]
NumberOfEntries=5

File000001=n000001.wav
Title000001=n000001.wav

File000002=n000002.wav
Title000002=n000002.wav

File000003=n000003.wav
Title000003=n000003.wav

File000004=p000004.wav
Title000004=p000004.wav

File000005=p000005.wav
Title000005=p000005.wav

Version=2
```

Can this be done in one instance?  The reason I ask is that I'm going to be running/calling the command (awk,grep,sed,etc...) from inside of octave/matlab after the initial process has completed creating the audio files.

example: of what I mean in one instance below:  (matlab/octave code)

```
  system(strcat({'split --lines=3600 -d '},dirpathwaveformstmp,fileallplaylistStr,{' '},dirpathwaveformstmp,'allsplit'))
```

This splits a single file into multiple files with the names allsplit01 allsplit02 etc.. and each file only has a max of 3600 lines.

For those who asked this is creating playlist files for audio files I create with octave/matlab.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the mentioned format the format that you have, or the format that you want? And what is the other one? Besides this could you briefly explain what you are trying to accomplish (or why)?

Comment: @Dennis I updated the question to address your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it with awk:

*parse.awk*

```
BEGIN {
  print "[playlist]"
  print "NumberOfEntries=" len "\n"
  i = 1
}

{
  gsub(".*/|;", "")
  printf "File%06d=%s\n" , i, $0
  printf "Title%06d=%s\n\n", i, $0
  i++
}

END {
  print "Version 2"
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -v len=$(wc -l < infile) -f parse.awk infile
```

Output:

```
[playlist]
NumberOfEntries=5

File000001=n000001.wav
Title000001=n000001.wav

File000002=n000002.wav
Title000002=n000002.wav

File000003=n000003.wav
Title000003=n000003.wav

File000004=p000004.wav
Title000004=p000004.wav

File000005=p000005.wav
Title000005=p000005.wav

Version 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing your program in Octave, why don't you do it in Octave as well? The language is not limited to numerical analysis. What you're trying to do can be done quite easily with Octave functions.

```
filepath     = "path for input file"
playlistpath = "path for output file" 
## read file and prepare cell array for printing
files = strsplit (fileread (filepath)', "\n");
if (isempty (files{end}))
  files(end) = [];
endif
[~, names, exts] = cellfun (@fileparts, files, "UniformOutput", false);
files = strcat (names, exts);
files(2,:) = files(1,:);
files(4,:) = files(1,:);
files(1,:) = num2cell (1:columns(files))(:);
files(3,:) = num2cell (1:columns(files))(:);

## write playlist
[fid, msg] = fopen (playlistpath, "w");
if (fid < 0)
  error ("Unable to fopen %s for writing: %s", playlistpath, msg);
endif
fprintf (fid, "[playlist]\n");
fprintf (fid, "NumberOfEntries=%i\n", columns (files));
fprintf (fid, "\n");
fprintf (fid, "File%06d=%s\nTitle%06d=%s\n\n", files{:});
fprintf (fid, "Version 2");

if (fclose (fid))
  error ("Unable to fclose file %s with FID %i", playlistpath, fid);
endif
```

Comment: It looks interesting and I would like to try it but some of the come back with errors
 [~, names, exts] = cellfun (@fileparts, files, "UniformOutput", false); and several other lines produce errors.

Comment: I try and fix another line and another error comes up like Index exceeds matrix dimension...

Comment: what octave version are you using? Because it works fine on 3.6.2 (and that's not even the latest release which is 3.6.4)

Comment: That may explain it I'm using the ones the are in ubuntu's repos 3.2.4

Comment: @RickT that version is *very* old. Upgrade. See [Octave wiki](http://wiki.octave.org/Debian). The page name is Debian but includes Debian derivatives (like Ubuntu).

Comment: can't upgrade yet since the new versions of octave doesn't work with the qtoctave GUI.  Hopefully they will build a GUI with Octave one of these days.